# Owned pointer to a trait

Tags: rust

Why does the following fail and how can I store owned pointers to traits?

```
trait Trait {};
struct Struct;
impl Trait for Struct {};

struct Container {
  child: ~Trait
};
let container = ~Container { child: ~Struct };
```

error: mismatched types: expected `~main::test02::Trait` but found `~main::test02::Struct` (expected trait `benchmark::test02::Trait` but found `~-ptr`)

Comment: Did you succeed by casting the value to your trait type as Ramon suggested? I'm trying the same and it compiles fine, but I get segfaults when running. I opened a bug for it: https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues/6717

Comment: @Andreas This is quite odd. I can confirm that your code crashed (even with some modifications - the problem is almost definitely there). However, I'm not sure that this is always crashes - don't know why this case is special.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to cast the value:

```
trait Trait {}
struct Struct;
impl Trait for Struct {}

struct Container {
  child : ~Trait
}
fn main() {
    let container = ~Container { child: ~Struct as ~Trait };
    println("")
}
```